# php - phpseclib - how to connect to ssh host via socks5 proxy (proxy with basic authentication user:password)

Tags: php, phpseclib, socks

php - phpseclib - how to connect to ssh host via socks5 proxy (proxy with basic authentication user:password)

we know method for ssh login via socks5 , but who knows how to connect via socks5 with basic authentication ?

in official example script there is no authentication method in use... :

```
$fsock = fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 1080, $errno, $errstr, 1);
if (!$fsock) {
    throw new \Exception($errstr);
}

$port = pack('n', $port);
$address = chr(strlen($address)) . $address;

$request = "\5\1\0";
if (fwrite($fsock, $request) != strlen($request)) {
    throw new \Exception('Premature termination');
}

$response = fread($fsock, 2);
if ($response != "\5\0") {
    throw new \Exception('Unsupported protocol or unsupported method');
}

$request = "\5\1\0\3$address$port";
if (fwrite($fsock, $request) != strlen($request)) {
    throw new \Exception('Premature termination');
}

$response = fread($fsock, strlen($address) + 6);
if (substr($response, 0, 2) != "\5\0") {
echo bin2hex($response) . "\n";
    throw new \Exception("Unsupported protocol or connection refused");
}

$ssh = new SSH2($fsock);
$ssh->login('username', 'password');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -latr');
```

Answer (score 1):

answer is:

```
    $fsock = fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 1080, $errno, $errstr, 1);
if (!$fsock) {
    throw new \Exception($errstr);
}

$port = pack('n', $port);
$address = chr(strlen($address)) . $address;

$request = "\5\1\2";    //2 - authentication method is user/password , 0 - no authentication
if (fwrite($fsock, $request) != strlen($request)) {
    throw new \Exception('Premature termination');
}

$response = fread($fsock, 2);
if ($response != "\5\2") {  //acceptance from server that user/password method (2) is supported
    throw new \Exception('Unsupported protocol or unsupported method');
}

//login password 
    
$request = pack('C2',0x01,strlen($proxyUser)).$proxyUser.pack('C1',strlen($proxyPass)).$proxyPass;

            if (fputs($fsock,$request) != strlen($request)) {
               exit("premature termination"); 
            }

            $response = fgets($fsock,3);
            echo "login confirmation status rcvd\n";

            if ($response != "\1\0") {
               exit("Login password incorrect");
            }

// end section for authentication , authentication done with success 

$request = "\5\1\0\3$address$port";
if (fwrite($fsock, $request) != strlen($request)) {
    throw new \Exception('Premature termination');
}

$response = fread($fsock, strlen($address) + 6);
if (substr($response, 0, 2) != "\5\0") {
echo bin2hex($response) . "\n";
    throw new \Exception("Unsupported protocol or connection refused");
}

$ssh = new SSH2($fsock);
$ssh->login('username', 'password');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -latr');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).